# login into two different areas on one login form

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to get user login into two different areas on one login form based on a criteria. The problem I'm having is that if the correct passwords are provided, everything works fine but when a wrong password is provided, nothing happens, it doesn't even echo the password error alert! What could be wrong and is my code okay?

Thanks

```
        if(isset($_POST['login'])){

        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];

        $username = stripslashes($username);
        $password = stripslashes($password);
        $username = $username;
        $password = $password;

        //$pass = md5($password);

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT password FROM table WHERE username=:username");
        $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount()<1){

        echo 'INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD';

        }else{
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        list($hash) = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        $status1 = "COMPLETED";
        $status2 = "UNCOMPLETED";

        $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT status FROM table WHERE username ='$_SESSION[username]'");
        $check = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $status = $check['status'];

        if(strcmp($status, $status1) == 0){

        header("location: completed/index.php");
        exit();
        }elseif(strcmp($status, $status2) == 0){

        header("location: uncompleted/index.php");  
        exit();
        }else{

        echo 'INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD';

        }   
        }
        }
        }
```

Comment: Did you start the session?

Comment: put `exit` just after when you are echoing the error message

Comment: @Fred-ii- he is not using session , he is just echoing the error messages..

Comment: @NishantSolanki I think he's using session --> `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;`.

Comment: @iRuth but here the question is for not displaying the error message, and for error message he is only using echo, not session...

Comment: @NishantSolanki `WHERE username ='$_SESSION[username]'` that's a username in a `where` clause, not an echo'd message and the query is dependant on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my else was in the wrong place. I had it after the if/elseif strcmp statements. It should be after the  if (password_verify($password, $hash))  block.

it was noticed from [phpfreak](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/294763-login-into-two-different-areas-on-one-login-form/?p=1506356) forum. Credits to him
thus the correct code:

```
            if(isset($_POST['login']))
            {
                $username = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
                $password = stripslashes($_POST['password']);

                $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT password FROM table WHERE username=:username");
                $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmt->execute();

                if($stmt->rowCount()<1)
                {
                    echo '<div class="signals"><p class="bg-warning text-center warning"><button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD</div></p>';
                }
                else
                {
                    $password = $_POST['password'];
                    list($hash) = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

                    if (password_verify($password, $hash))
                    {
                        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

                        $status1 = "COMPLETED";
                        $status2 = "UNCOMPLETED";

                        $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT status FROM table WHERE username ='$_SESSION[username]'");
                        $check = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        $status = $check['status'];

                        if(strcmp($status, $status1) == 0)
                        {
                            header("location: completed/index.php");
                            exit();
                        }
                        elseif(strcmp($status, $status2) == 0)
                        {
                            header("location: uncompleted/index.php");    
                            exit();
                        }  
                    }
                    else
                    { 
                        echo '<div class="signals"><p class="bg-warning text-center warning"><button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD again</div></p>';
                    } 
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you did not handle the condition where `password_verify($password, $hash)` returns `false` in your if-statement. I handled it below:

```
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $username = $username;
    $password = $password;

    //$pass = md5($password);

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT password FROM table WHERE username=:username");
    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->rowCount() < 1) {

        echo 'INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD';
    } else {
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        list($hash) = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

        if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

            $status1 = "COMPLETED";
            $status2 = "UNCOMPLETED";

            $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT status FROM table WHERE username ='$_SESSION[username]'");
            $check = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $status = $check['status'];

            if (strcmp($status, $status1) == 0) {

                header("location: completed/index.php");
                exit();
            } elseif (strcmp($status, $status2) == 0) {

                header("location: uncompleted/index.php");
                exit();
            } else {

                echo 'INVALID USERNAME OR PASSWORD';
            }
        } else {
            // handle wrong password here 
            echo 'INVALID PASSWORD';
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: didn't work either. still behaves like mine. the issue is that when a correct password is provided, it redirects to the right page but when a wrong password is provided, it just bounces without throwing any error

Comment: @Chidi Okay. What do you mean by `bouces`?